# Ember : fetch data afterwards

Tags: ember.js

I get some data from my API through model in route.js. This data contains somewhere an id on its own, with no relationships or included stuff to get details. So I have to make another API request to get the object with that id.

I did it with a component (to be able to send the id argument) and it works, but I would like to know if that's the way to go and if so, if I did it right and it cannot be simplified (because it looks complex to me for such a simple task):

I call my component with `{{resource-name id=evaluation.manager}}`

Component template just contains `{{name}}`

component.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    store: Ember.inject.service(),
    _getResource(id) {
        return this.get('store').findRecord('resource', id);
    },
    resource: Ember.computed('id', function() {
        const id = this.get('id');
        const proxy = Ember.ObjectProxy.extend(Ember.PromiseProxyMixin);
        return proxy.create({
            promise: this._getResource(id)
        });
    }),
    name: Ember.computed('resource.isFulfilled', function() {
        if (this.get('resource.isFulfilled')) {
            return `${this.get('resource.lastName')} ${this.get('resource.firstName')}`;
        }
        else {
            return "...";
        }
    }),
    didReceiveAttrs() {
        const id = this.getAttr('id');
        Ember.assert('resource-name must have an "id" attribute!', !Ember.isBlank(id));
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the question? At first glance I would think a route is the right place. It should fetch the resource and if sub resources are needed chain the promise inside the route. That way the ember loading subsystem can manage the network delay and user feedback. BTW your understanding of the PromiseProxyMixin is correct. I've done that same thing in components where the network resource is not associated with the current route but used to display side data (like related articles or something).

Comment: You could also move the name logic into the template. PromiseProxyMixin properties are accessible in a template.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I just wanted to know if that was the correct way. It's used for side data indeed.

Comment: Correctness is a subjective term. But I'd say I would approach the same problem the same way you did. For reference I covered this very topic at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ember.js/1054/asynchronous-tasks-in-components#t=201608081012449986967 with the `PromiseProxyMixin` and with using [ember-concurrency](http://ember-concurrency.com/#/docs) (which is an even better solution IMHO).

Comment: Thanks! I am new to Ember so your article is quite valuable to me.